# Can we create texture views with 1 of the dim(width/height/depth) smaller than that of base texture but same number of mipmap levels and layers?

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, opengl-4

I know that we can use certain mipmap levels and/or layers of a texture as views.

e.g, If we have a texture 2d array of size 64x64 with 12 layers and 7 mipmpap levels, I can create as view the following:

- texture 2d of size 64x64 with n mipmap levels (n= 0 to 6).
- texture 2d of size 16x16 with n mipmap levels (n= 0 to 4).
- and so on..
- texture 2d array of size 64x64 with  n mipmap levels (n= 0 to 6) and x layers(x=0 to 11)
- texture 2d array of size 32x32 with  n mipmap levels (n= 0 to 5) and x layers(x=0 to 11)
- and so on..

But the glTextureView command does not ask the individual dimension of the view that must be created. Is it understood from the mipmap levels that we choose? Taking the exammple above, cant we create a texture 2D view with size say 64x32 and 7 mipmap levels, and 12 layers?
i.e it will be using exactly half subimage of the original texture for all mipmap levels and layers..?

Answer (score 1):

No, [GL_ARB_texture_view](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_view.txt) does not provide the functionality you are looking for (and also no other feature of the GL does) . What do you need this for? If you only want to use a sub-image of the texture, you can work with texture coordinates.

Comment: I have a program that creates hundreds of textures at runtime, and all these textures are of random size and are read only. I want to use texture views for maximum sharing of data storage between them. I create 1 large storage for view of size 1024x1024 and want all other textures that are smaller (say 500x500) to use the original texture as view. I did this and GL did not complain with any invalid  operation error. What you are saying is that I should resize my smaller texture to 512x512(yes it is possible to resize) and use 2nd mipmap of original texture..?

Comment: I edited my answer, since the wording was not clear. Texture views are a way to _reinterprete_ the data. Just using a sub-region does not require any reinterpretation - you do not need different views for that at all.